# Set the background color of nested elements from a repeating color swatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a fluid block layout running on this front end I’m working on.  I want set the background color of a div with a certain class or it’s inner paragraph tag to a color that is taken from a five to eight color swatch that repeats.  Example: red, green, blue, pink, yellow, red, green, blue, pink, yellow….

Originally I thought that this would be kinda straight forward using nth-child pseudo selector with a bit of added uglification via class/id selection, but the elements are nested within a few divs and I can’t get it to work.  I’m not sure if I should be using javascript here or not, obviously I’d rather get it done with CSS as my javascript is quite weak, but I really don’t mind either way if someone can help me with a solution.  I’ve had a look around and I understand how examples like http://jsfiddle.net/eudLg58p/ work, but I just can’t get that extra step to selecting nested divs.  It’s possible I’m barking up the wrong tree.

Here's the markup..

```
<div id="bhe-body">

    <div id="breadcrumbs">
        <div>
            <h1 class="font-purple font20 center">Home / Sample / Sample Directory</h1>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img id="back-arrow" src="mcwh-img/back-arrow.png">
            <img id="home-button" src="mcwh-img/home-icon.png">
        </div>
    </div>



    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon q" id="">
            <div class="icon-type"></div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type"></div>
            <p class="">Directory two</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type"></div>
            <p class="">Directory three</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type dir"></div>
            <p class="">Directory four</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type dir"></div>
            <p class="">Directory five</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type dir"></div>
            <p class="">Directory six</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type dir"></div>
            <p class="">Directory seven</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type dir"></div>
            <p class="">Directory eight</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon" id="">
            <div class="icon-type dir"></div>
            <p class="">Directory nine</p><!-- color needed here -->
        </div>          
    </a>


    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon triangle-border-1" id="">

            <div class="icon-type go-back">
                <img id="back-arrow-lower" src="mcwh-img/back-arrow-white.png">
            </div>

        </div>          
    </a>


    <a href="#">
        <div class="bhe-icon triangle-border-2" id="">

            <div class="icon-type home">
                <img src="mcwh-img/home-icon-white.png">
            </div>

        </div>          
    </a>

</div>
```

..and here is my CSS...

```
.icon-type{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


#bhe-body .icon-type p:nth-child(5n + 1){
  color: pink;
}

#bhe-body .icon-type p:nth-child(5n + 2){
  color: red;
}

#bhe-body .icon-type p:nth-child(5n + 3){
  color: green;
}

#bhe-body .icon-type p:nth-child(5n + 4){
  color: orange;
}

#bhe-body .icon-type p:nth-child(5n + 5){
  color: purple;
}
```

My gut feeling is that I don't completely understand how the pseudo selector works and it possibly may not be the most efficient way to handle this task.

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector applies to siblings of the same parent. The `<p>` elements are not siblings, but the `<a>` elements are. Also, the `<p>` elements are not descendants of the elements with the `icon-type` class.

You could try:

```
#bhe-body > a:nth-child(5n + 1) > .bhe-icon >  p {
  color: pink;
}
```

But since the `<div id="breadcrumbs">` element is also a sibling of the `<a>` elements, you could use the [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector instead. It is similar to the `nth-child` selector, but considers only elements of the same type when numerating the siblings.

```
#bhe-body > a:nth-of-type(5n + 1) > .bhe-icon >  p {
    color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, I don't quite understand the selector terms but I can get it working. I've created a fiddle for it here...  
https://jsfiddle.net/DeanActual/29u3jwtn/

Here’s also the same thing applied to background color..
https://jsfiddle.net/DeanActual/gghdv530/

I’ve attempted to take it a step further and have the color pallet appear on a hover.  This is kinda working but all of the divs come on all at the same time.
https://jsfiddle.net/DeanActual/bkpgpkme/

Answer (score 0):

Not like that Football, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/eudLg58p/1/

```
/* 1, 6, 11 ... */
section:nth-of-type(5n - 4) { 
    background-color: red;
}

/* 2, 7, 12 ... */
section:nth-of-type(5n - 3) {
    background-color: orange;
}

/* 3, 8, 13 ... */
section:nth-of-type(5n - 2) {
    background-color: blue;
}

/* you get the point ... */
section:nth-of-type(5n - 1) {
    background-color: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(5n - 0) {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

(for the hillarious Football reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-AA3lk53DA&t=54)

Comment: Haha yeah I am football :|